# video.js mp4 fallback is not working in android phone

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am trying to play video in android but this doesn't work:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html> 
    <head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.10/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.10/video.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body> 
   <video id="GSGM_Final_Video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
     preload="auto" width="500" height="315" data-setup="{}">
   <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm'>
   <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>

   <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
   </video>

</body> 
</html>
```

However this seems to be working in all desktop browsers and iOS devices except on Android.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: A more complete example would be useful.

Comment: modified to add complete code example.